# How to trace a url redirect route in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Hello i have been trying to trace redirect routes of a url which redirect about 3 to 4 time with respect to user ip address and location.

So i suppose it has to be in javascript.

Anyone know a way or any javascript library that does this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to know which page redirected to your page, you can use `window.referrer`.

Comment: Use the Network tab in the browser console.

Comment: I want the final url in a javascript variable.  Can we do that with browser console?

Comment: I dont think you can do this with browserside JS.  Time to break out some serverside code